# HABTM associations in Rails : collecting and counting the categories of a model's children

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship setup. It looks like this:

- books `have_and_belong_to_many` categories
- categories `have_and_belongs_to_many` books
- a store `has_many` books
- a book `belongs_to` a store

I'm trying to show how many books in each store belong to each category. So my view would show Store X has 200 books and 80 of them are mystery, 60 are non fiction, etc.

I have been trying out a bunch of different ways of doing this, but no success so far. I think I'm starting in the wrong place. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks

This is Rails 4 and psql by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that you have a `books_categories` join table you can add a `has_many :categories, through: :books` association to which links `stores` and `categories` through `books`.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :categories, through: :books
end
```

That's the easy part. Now lets get each category and the books count (revised):

```
def books_per_category
  categories.select('categories.id, categories.name, count(books.id) as count')
            .group('categories.id, categories.name')
            .map do |c|
    {
      name: c.name,
      count: c.count
    }
  end
end
```

**Courtesy of [@jakub-kosiński](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133478/rails-get-count-of-association-through-join-table/30133892?noredirect=1#comment48379098_30133892)**

Comment: I created an offshoot question to see if the where more performant ways of achieving the task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133478/rails-get-count-of-association-through-join-table

Answer (score 2):

Generally, instead of using Rails' built-in 'has_and_belongs_to_many' method, it is better practice to use a join table.  In this setup, you have three tables:

- Books
- Categories
- BookCategories

The BookCategories (or whatever you decide to call it) is a join table that belongs_to both Books and Categories and has a Foreign ID of each.  You would then use Rails' "has_many :through" to link the Books and Categories.

The store would have a 'has_many' relationship with books.  With the prior relationship setup right, you can then use this method to get the count for a store for a particular category:

```
Store.books.where(category:'Mystery')
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be getting me closer. But I get this error when I try to use that method: 

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column books.category does not exist

Is this because in the model the relationship is defined as has_many :categories so it doesn't recognize 'category'?

Comment: This answer is pretty confusing. Setting up the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relations would also require a join table. Where else would you store the association? You're on the right track with  `has_many :through` but everything else about this answer is pretty much off.