# Rails get count of association through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql

This question is an offshoot from [HABTM associations in Rails : collecting and counting the categories of a model's children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130380/habtm-associations-in-rails-collecting-and-counting-the-categories-of-a-model/30132930#30132930).

### Given:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  has_many :categories, through: :books
end
```

### The task:

**Given a store, list the number of books per category.**

```
Store.first.books_per_category
```

desired output:

```
[ { name: 'mystery', count: 5 }, { name: 'fantasy', count: 6 } ]
```

**However each store may have an enormous amount of books and categories**.

I am trying to create a single performant query which only gets the name column and a count of the Books for each distinct Category associated with a Store, without loading books into memory.

### I have tried so far:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Will load each book into memory
  def books_per_category
    categories.eager_load(:books).map do |c|
      {
          name: c.name,
          count: c.books.size # Using size instead of count is important since count will always query the DB
      }
    end
  end

  # will query books count for each category.
  def books_per_category2
    categories.distinct.map do |c|
      {
          name: c.name,
          count: c.books.count
      }
    end
  end
end
```

### Database schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150508184514) do

  create_table "books", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "store_id"
  end

  add_index "books", ["store_id"], name: "index_books_on_store_id"

  create_table "books_categories", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "book_id",     null: false
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
  end

  add_index "books_categories", ["book_id", "category_id"], name: "index_books_categories_on_book_id_and_category_id"
  add_index "books_categories", ["category_id", "book_id"], name: "index_books_categories_on_category_id_and_book_id"

  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "stores", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Comment: Source code: https://github.com/maxcal/sampleapp/tree/30133478

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use chain `select` and `group` to aggregate the count of books for each category. Your `books_per_category` method may look like this:

```
def books_per_category
  categories.select('categories.id, categories.name, count(books.id) as count')
            .group('categories.id, categories.name').map do |c|
    {
      name: c.name,
      count: c.count
    }
  end
end
```

This will produce the following SQL query:

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.name, count(books.id) as count 
  FROM "categories" 
  INNER JOIN "books_categories" ON "categories"."id" = "books_categories"."category_id" 
  INNER JOIN "books" ON "books_categories"."book_id" = "books"."id" 
  WHERE "books"."store_id" = 1 
  GROUP BY categories.id, categories.name
```

Comment: Works really well - runs at about 5-10ms on set of ca 500 books on my MacBook air which currently sounds like its having an astma attack.

Answer (score 12):

You'll want to be creating a method (or scope) on the Categories object so something like.

```
Category.joins(:books)
        .select('categories.*, COUNT(books.id) as book_count')
        .group('categories.id')
```

the resulting object will now have every attribute of an instance of category and respond to a method, `book_count` which returns the number of books with that instances category id.

It is noteworthy to mention this will omit any categories that do not have books associated with them. if you want to include those, the query needs to be updated to the following:

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:books)
        .select('categories.*, COUNT(books_categories.book_id) as book_count')
        .group('categories.id')
```

Comment: Thanks but both are significantly slower than the solution provided by @jakub-kosiński (815.9ms/807.9ms vs 10.5ms).

Comment: How fast is `select categories.name` vs `categories.*`

Comment: `select categories.name` is marginally faster - about 10-100ms.

Comment: You can try it yourself if you want [repo](https://github.com/maxcal/sampleapp/tree/30133478) your answer was sort of "some assembly required" so I hope I did'nt mess up the implementation. I tested it by seeding a Postgres db and running `Store.first.books_per_category4` from the console.

Comment: Lol I believe you, I was just curious.

Comment: it does not seem to keep the count attribute for me (I get `undefined method`). Maybe a Rails version issue? I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2