# Trying to get count of products in each category in Thinking Sphinx

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using Thinking Sphinx and want to get count of products for each category. My index file:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, :with => :active_record do
  # fields
  indexes title, :sortable => true
  indexes product_category_id

  has created_at, updated_at
end
```

I tried to use query, using group_by

```
Product.search('phone').group_by(&:product_category_id)
```

But it returns me grouped hash with all search results, but I want to see only count, and want to make this query much lighter.

Also I tried query

```
Product.search('phone', :select => 'COUNT(product.id) as cr').group_by(&:market_id)
```

But it returns error

```
<ThinkingSphinx::SyntaxError: sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting DISTINCT or '*' near 'product.id) as cr FROM `product_core` WHERE MATCH('phone') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META' - SELECT COUNT(product.id) as cr FROM `product_core` WHERE MATCH('phone') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 0, 20; SHOW META>
```

Comment: try append .count() with the column name within the parentheses to your query

Comment: I tried to do it, but simpe count() returns just the size of hash, and count with column name returns 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133478/rails-get-count-of-association-through-join-table Simular scenario but solved with just ActiveRecord.

Comment: I got it, but I can not add select condition to sphinx search method

Comment: Try using `count(*)` sphinx doesn't actually support naming a column for a non distinct count

Comment: I tried this also, didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [on GitHub](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/915):

Facet queries are what you'll want to use for this:
http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/facets.html

Two aspects to it - firstly, you'll want to convert product_category_id from a field to an attribute and set it to be a facet:

```
has product_category_id, :facet => true
```

And then you can make a facet call to get the summary information you're after:

```
Product.facets('phone')[:product_category_id]
```